# Replacing a string in column names in dataframe in R with grepl

Tags: r, dataframe, gsub

I have a dataframe and some of the columns begin with 'dfall$PROFESSION' which I want to delete. I.e.:

```
"dfall$PROFESSIONBusinessman"             "dfall$PROFESSIONDoctor"                 
[35] "dfall$PROFESSIONEngineer"                "dfall$PROFESSIONFarmer"                 
[37] "dfall$PROFESSIONHousewife"               "dfall$PROFESSIONLawyer"                 
[39] "dfall$PROFESSIONMissing"                 "dfall$PROFESSIONPensioner"
```

So I tried:

```
names(df_all) <- gsub("dfall$PROFESSION", "", names(df_all))
```

However, this does not effect any change.  Can you explain it?  What should I do instead?

Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that you only want to delete "PROFESSION" from the column name?

Comment: you need to add `fixed = TRUE` inside `gsub` (i.e. `gsub("dfall$PROFESSION", "", "dfall$PROFESSIONFarmer", fixed = TRUE)`....or escappe the `$` (i.e. `gsub("dfall\\$PROFESSION", "", "dfall$PROFESSIONFarmer")`)

Answer (score 14):

You can change the names with `gsub` but you must also save them back into the data.frame.

```
colnames(dfall) = gsub("PROFESSION", "", colnames(dfall))
```

You can't get rid of the `dfall$` part. That is not really part of the column name, rather `dfall$PROFESSIONEngineer` specifies the `PROFESSIONEngineer` column of the `dfall` data.frame .

Comment: If I need to replace multiple characters: `:`, `(` and `)`?

Comment: @ahbon   I am not sure what you want to replace with what.  If you want to remove any instance of `:`, `(` or `)`,  try `gsub("[:()]", "", String)`