# Replace typo over column names

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose the next dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame("level.3.london"=seq(1,5), "level.2.bogota"=seq(1,5), "level"=seq(1,5))
```

Is it possible to replace `.` for an space over the dataframe column names?
The idea is to get the next output:

```
names(df)
```

Console output:

```
[1] "level 3 london" "level 2 bogota" "level"
```

Comment: No, names of objects in R cannot contain spaces!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing a string in column names in dataframe in R with grepl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42892322/replacing-a-string-in-column-names-in-dataframe-in-r-with-grepl)

Comment: @PaulS, column names can contain spaces, but it's rarely desirable.

Comment: Thanks, @jdobres, I have just learned that from your answer! I have been convinced of the contrary for years!

Comment: I agree with comments here. A better practice would be to replace with underscore i.e. `_`

Comment: @PaulS even something like `my var <- 1:10` is valid, strangely enough. You just have to use backticks around the variable name (which I can't seem to get working in a comment). We're all learning today!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regular expression and the `names` function should do what you want, but be warned that column names with spaces can be difficult to work with.

```
names(df) <- gsub('\\.', ' ', names(df))
```

If you want to reference those column names, you will need to enclose them in backticks:

```
df$`level 3 London`
```